# Nav button design issue

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to design my nav (4 items in total) to be in circles each spaced about 20 px apart, located on the top right of my screen. I got everything to "work" design wise, however, now that every nav item appears how I want it (in its own a circle), when I go to have them all positioned on the upper right the first 3 nav items have disappeared and only the 4th nav item is visible. Please help!

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">The Story </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Design </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Specs </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Gallery </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbutton {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4FA5B1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 100px;}

ul {
    width: 50x;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 15%;
}
```

Comment: First, you have invalid html here.` first li a` <a/> --> </a>

Comment: Second, you have invalid value for ul width --> width: 50x; --> width: 50px;

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```css
#nav{
  position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
  right: 100px;
}
.navbutton {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4FA5B1;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">The Story </a></li>
<li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Design </a></li>
<li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Specs </a></li>
<li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Gallery </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
#nav{
  position: absolute;
   top: 50px;
  right: 100px;
}
.navbutton {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4FA5B1;
}

ul {
    width: 50x;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `navbutton` elements have `position: absolute` so they overlap each other, i.e. only the last one is visible.

Try this snippet:

```css
.navbutton {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4FA5B1;
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

ul {
    width: 50x;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">The Story </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Design </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Specs </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#" class="navbutton">Gallery </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the navigation to be in the top right corner of the page use this CSS:

```
#nav { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
}

#nav li { 
    display: inline-block; 
}

.navbutton {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4FA5B1;
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

ul {
    width: 50x;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 20px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  #nav{
   position:absolute;
   top: 50px;
 right: 100px;
  }
  .navbutton {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 108px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4FA5B1;
  
}

ul {
       padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
        margin: 20px; 
 float:left;
}
```